# How do I keep a mediawiki div element centered horizontally?

Tags: css

```
#searchInput {
        width: 50%;
        height: 40px;
        display: block;
        text-align: center;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
        top: -12em !important;
        left: 1em !important;
}
```

I can't get this div to stay centered in my mediawiki wiki. Is there a way to do this? The code above doesn't do anything. It just stays in place. I have applied what I know in previous post, and it still doesn't work for certain divs.

Comment: Could you please trim down your code to the minimal code necessary to still reproduce the issue?  Also, please include the HTML.

Comment: including the html may be a bit hard because the css external stylesheet is conntrolling at least 10 files worth of php with html in them and i dont know which file its in. i did trim the code though.