# Why is the !important property not being applied?

Tags: css

```
    #searchInput {
    width: 50% !important;
    height: 50% !important;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    margin-left: auto !important;
    margin-right: auto !important;
    text-align: center !important;
    color: #FF7F27;
    top: -300px !important;
    left: 100px !important;
    background: transparent;
    font-size: 85%;
```

I'm doing this in main.css for monobook skin in mediawiki. For some reason, main.css is ignoring my `!important` because it's still not centering the div. What am I doing wrong to have my code keep getting ignored? How can I fix this? Im not asking how to center. Im asking why my divs code is bein ignored even when its proper.

Comment: That is not the way you center a div, also you shouldn't be using `!important` at all

Comment: The `!important` is not a tag, and tags are not supposed to execute anyway.

Comment: this will be helpful [Stackoverflow post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/189621/when-does-csss-important-declaration-not-work)

Comment: I agree with @Mr.Alien ... if centering a div is what you are actually going for.  Could you please explain (in the original question) what you are trying to do?

Comment: This is possibly a duplicate of [How do I keep a mediawiki div centered horizontally](http://stackoverflow.com/q/29395911/2065237)?  It's the same user.  @user47759 Please do not post duplicate questions.  If you feel your original question is not getting adequate attention, you should consider improving that question, not posting another.

Comment: `text-align: center` gives the effect of centering **text** (and other inline elements) *inside* the div.  It does not center the div.  Therefore, your approach is wrong.  Setting `margin-left` and `margin-right` to `auto` is **the way** to center a div.

Comment: Im not asking how to center a div im asking why my important tag is being ignored. I ahve included the proper centering code in my css file. but its still wont center. its because the code is getting ignored which is something you guys should know about.

Comment: Exactly what property you think is ignored? You should find and check first parent element with position **not** static, all your css values are connected to it (check its position, height and width in Inspector).

Comment: I think my code for this div is not taking precedence. I created my own div for my wiki that runs fine with the centereing code, but all the divs i did nto create myself ignore the centering code and the code does not take precedence.

Comment: And I think you are not sure about it. So, please open the Inspector and check for **css calculated** values, there you will also see where in CSS they are defined. Your question should state `How to trace what styles were applied to html tag` - if you knew that, than you wouldn't ask the current question.

Comment: You need to get rid of `width: 100%` for this to work.

Comment: i checked the css for the inspector and it does show my code that i posted. so if thats not the problem why wont it execute?

Comment: changed the width to 50%. still same problem.

Comment: this is why i think its precedence is being overridden. its the same for all the divs i didnt make. When i make a js fiddle with the code give to me it works fine. in main.css for mediawiki it doesnt.

Comment: here is the link to the mobile site im creating. it shows the one div i created working and all others not http://www.responsivetest.net/#u=http://citysage.ninja/main/index.php?title=Welcome!&redirect=yes|363|454|1

Answer (score 0):

Technically, this div is already centered because the width is 100%...

We need to see the bigger picture here as presumably this div is inside something else which is prompting you to try to override said div's css using `!important`?

This is the kind of thing you should be doing:

```
 body {width: 100%}
 #searchInput {width:50%; margin: 0 auto; display: block;}
```

which would end up with a centered `#searchInput` div on the page...

http://jsfiddle.net/ndmdpd69/

Comment: I have added everything you typed and still nothing.

Comment: can you create a jsfiddle with more detail? i.e. your css  / hmtl

Comment: yeah i can include the code for my external css that controls the page look for the skin im modifying https://jsfiddle.net/matsuiny2004/j0k103kk/ the html will be hrd since its mixed with php and spread through many files and filetypes.